# Laravel I want to return a sorted item with the condition Hour and Day which I added earlier in my database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.3, conditional-statements, return-value

```php
@foreach($items as $item)
                    <option value="{{ $item->itemCode }}" data-hour="{{ (count($item->rates()->hour()) > 0) ? $item->rates()->latestHour()->amount : '0' }}" data-day="{{ (count($item->rates()->day()) > 0) ? $item->rates()->latestDay()->amount : '0' }}" id="#itemopt{{ $item->itemCode }}">{{ $item->itemName }}</option>
@endforeach
```

So i want to get the item after sorting from the Unit condition Day and Hour, actually before that, i save item with a rate that have day and hour condition too, so it will be easier for me to compute the amount if i get a sorted item return here

Thanks for some answer [image: 1]

Comment: elaborate your question?

Comment: do you understand the exact requirement of the OP, whoever upvoted this question? can you please elaborate?

Comment: I was asking, how can i get the items, through a condition if its day or hour , which i flag in my db as the unit type of my item